# VHDL-2008 instantiation using hierarchical library path?

Tags: vhdl

What do you call a VHDL instantiation that looks like this?:

```
  Osvvm.TbUtilPkg.CreateClock ( 
    Clk        => Clk, 
    Period     => Tperiod_Clk 
  );
```

Is this new to VHDL-2008?  What are the rules to use this type of instantiation?  It looks like they also relaxed the rules to allow anonymous instance names?

Here's the code I took the above snippet of code out of:

```
library ieee ;
  use ieee.std_logic_1164.all ;
  use ieee.numeric_std.all ;
  use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all ;

library osvvm ;
context osvvm.OsvvmContext ;
    
library osvvm_AXI4 ;
context osvvm_AXI4.AxiStreamContext ;
    
entity TbStream is
end entity TbStream ; 
architecture TestHarness of TbStream is

begin

  -- create Clock 
  Osvvm.TbUtilPkg.CreateClock ( 
    Clk        => Clk, 
    Period     => Tperiod_Clk 
  ); 
  
end entity;
```

Comment: That is not an instance. That is a procedure call. Calls like that could be done in VHDL 87 afaik.

Comment: Sorry, my background is Verilog.  Can you call a procedure if its not in a process in VHDL?

Comment: Yes. Any "one liner" in VHDL is effectively an inferred process. See VHDL LRM 2008 11.4 Concurrent procedure call statements.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11. Concurrent statements 11. 1 General "The primary concurrent statements are the block statement, which groups together other concurrent statements, and the process statement, which represents a single independent sequential process. Additional concurrent statements provide convenient syntax for representing simple, commonly occurring forms of processes, as well as for representing structural decomposition and regular descriptions." (11.4) "A concurrent procedure call statement represents a process containing the corresponding sequential procedure call statement." ...

Comment: Calling a procedure this way illuminates its source.   Library is OSVVM.   Package is TbUtilPkg.   Subprogram (here procedure) is CreateClock.   Often people ask where something is, this answers the question.  For example, in my testbenches, I call the stop as `std.env.stop`.   By doing that I am telling people this is something in the standard library `std` and the standard package `env`.   Otherwise, people would wonder, is stop provided by the VHDL standard (yes) or OSVVM (no).

Comment: You can think of a concurrent procedure call as an instance of an entity that has only one process.

Comment: Jim's analogy *...instance of an entity that has only one process* breaks down when signal declarations aren't subprogram declarative items (a property shared with process declarative items) and there can only be sequential statements. A concurrent procedure call cannot represent design hierarchy. Subprogram instantiation is a declaration, not a call (IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.4 Subprogram instantiation declarations).

Comment: The dotted name is just a "qualified name". To read it : Follow the library/use/(context) clauses to find the declaration it's referring to. So, `Osvvm.TbUtilPkg.CreateClock` comes from library `OSVVM`; which contains `TbUtilPkg` which is likely to be a package, listed in one of those context clauses (most likely `OsvvmContext`). Then, look at the TbUtilPkg.vhd file; the package declaration MUST contain something called `CreateClock` with a signature (parameters for a procedure, ports for an entity) matching that call (or instantiation). Good tools will find it for you...